# How to programmatically pin a document to the top of a modern library

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-document-library

Which CSOM c# or PowerShell Code I would have to use, to pin a document or link in a modern document library to the top?
I want to provision a document library, with one document which should be pinned on top by default.

Comment: Did you ever found an answer to this question, the one below from Derek is a workaround with rebuilding something that would already be available but there may be no API for it yet?

Answer (score 3):

Create a yes/no column ("IsPinned") on the library and sort your view by that column. You don't need any code.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I want to provision a document library, with one document which should be pinned on top by default.

Comment: Agree with @DerekGusoff - this is a good approach and "does the job". The document will always be first on top. If You want, You can do this with code (PowerShell or C#)

Comment: The question is: what are the code lines to do that (how to PROGRAMMATICALLY...)

Comment: Fine, create the isPinned property in code. A Google search should help you with that. It's the only way to store the pinned state of a document or list item.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9fe514ae-29c7-4ed9-8634-172cdc3049c5/create-yesno-field-programmatically?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Comment: I want to provision a doc lib with a pinned file without user interaction. The question for me is how to get and set the pinned state programmatically? A rest call showed me that there is no field which would expose the pinned state of a document.

Comment: That's correct, you need to create a field for that.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine was able to analyse the network traffic that happens, when a users clicks the "Pin to top" button and gave me the REST API call. As I am using PnP PowerShell I created a function that can be called to PIN an item to the top:

```
function Set-ListItemPinnedToTop
{
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $ServerRelativeListUrl,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Guid] $ViewId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [int] $ItemId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $FolderPath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [int] $AfterItemId=-1
  )

  $encodedDecodedUrl = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("'$ServerRelativeListUrl'") # a1
  $encodedViewGuid = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("'$($ViewId.ToString())'") # a2
  $encodedItemId = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("'$ItemId'") # a3
  $encodedFolderPath = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("'$FolderPath'") # a4
  $afterItemIdStr = $AfterItemId.ToString() # a5

  $result = Invoke-PnPSPRestMethod -Method Post `
      -Url "/_api/web/GetListUsingPath(DecodedUrl=@a1)/GetView(viewGuid=@a2)/AddToSpotlight(itemId=@a3,folderPath=@a4,afterItemId=@a5)?@a1=$encodedDecodedUrl&@a2=$encodedViewGuid&@a3=$encodedItemId&@a4=$encodedFolderPath&@a5=$afterItemIdStr" `
      -Content "{}" | Out-Null
}
```

Example URL (directly using the PnP method, to give you an idea, what the values look like):

```
Invoke-PnPSPRestMethod -Method Post `
-Url "/_api/web/GetListUsingPath(DecodedUrl=@a1)/GetView(viewGuid=@a2)/AddToSpotlight(itemId=@a3,folderPath=@a4,afterItemId=@a5)?@a1=%27%2Fsites%2FSiteXY%2DAPP%2FDossierDocs%27&@a2=%2774d11a1a%2D6502%2D43dd%2D84ab%2Dce9d2ae4489c%27&@a3=%2728%27&@a4=%27%2Fsites%2FSiteXY%2DAPP%2FDossierDocs%2FDossier%2D1%2Fggg%27&@a5=-1" `
-Content "{}"
```